# Dependency injection in java spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have gone through many of the stackoverflow answers for the same but I think I am still not clear. What I understood is:

1. If we create direct objects like `A a=new A();` it would be
   difficult to change/handle information everytime.
2. Dependency injection provides us what we want at runtime instead of compile time.
3. In spring to achieve to dependency injection we must use
   parameterized constructors and setter methods (mandatory).
4. Dependency injection is used to keep your code CLEAN and STABLE.
   What do you mean  by clean and stable ?? (Please elaborate if you
   know in SIMPLE words)

This is what I understood so far. Please correct me wherever I am wrong and please add some points (if any) in very SIMPLE words so that I can understand easily.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the main purpose of dependency injection is to make testing easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1 is correct, creating an object using a new operator will
   leads to tight coupling with the dependency. See the below
   configuration:-

```
 <!--This is the material used for construction of structures -->
    <bean id="constructionMaterial" class="com.construction.Brick" />

 <!--Below are the three constructions structures -->
    <bean id="building1" class="com.construction.structures.School">
    <property name="material" ref="constructionMaterial" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="building2" class="com.construction.structures.College">
    <property name="material" ref="constructionMaterial" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="building3" class="com.construction.structures.Hospital">
    <property name="material" ref="constructionMaterial" />
    </bean>
```

In above example suppose, if the construction material changed I just need to change the bean definition of constructionMaterial.

If you would have used the new operator, you had to change the code in three classes School, College, Hospital. Still looks fine, consider if there were 1000 different structures.

> Dependency injection also makes testing quite easy, well tested code
>   is stable.

```
 Class A{
      public String method1(){
         B calcObject=new B();
         return "Calculated value is:"+calcObject.calculation(); 
         }
     }
```

If I need to unit test method1() of class A, it's not possible to do it without testing calculation() of class B, which in turn conflicts concept of unit testing.

If I change the code like below:

```
   Class A{

     private B b;

      public String method1(){
         return "Calculated value is:"+b.calculation(); 
         }
     public void setB(B b){
       this.b=b;
          }

     }
```

In this case I can easily mock the object of class B and perform the unit testing of method1() of class. You can checkout how to perform testing using mock objects [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/11/unit-testing-using-mocks-testing.html). Dependency injection is a savior here once again.

Point 3 is not correct, if you are using annotations like @Autowired even if you don't put the setter method or use parameterized constructor,  it's fine. 
In this case dependency is injected by Reflection.

Comment: Thank you so much @Amit sir

Answer (score 0):

this is not easy to understand it was hard for me too so don't worry.

> If we create direct objects like A a=new A(); it would be difficult to
>   change/handle information everytime.

If the code is written good it shouldn't be difficult, spring is just providing configuration for this.

2 and 3, yes that is correct.

About 4, clean means you wont have code to handle the actual injection, meaning
lines like `A a=new A(B,C,D);`, we "inject" the dependencies in A, spring does it for us.

Stable means, you need to have valid sprint configuration to run you code, this guarantees the injected objects are of the required type and initialized in the correct order.

Another huge advantage in using spring is object reusability. As you might have already noticed you use predefined objects to inject, which get initialized only ONCE, this is hard to achieve without spring and usually in big projects it is even impossible.

Further more to use spring you are forced to use some of the best OOP practices, otherwise you won be able to use spring at all.

You use Interfaces in spring, so as you mentioned its very easy to change the implementing class to inject.

And finally it provides a single config xml file holding all your dependencies how cool is that :)

Comment: thank you so much @Borislav sir :)